# innerText polyfill for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, cross-browser

In WebKit `innerText` seems to return the text of the element that the user **sees** which is exactly what I need.

Are there any polyfills for Firefox?

For example:

```
<div id='1'><br> f<div style='display:none'>no</div>oo   bar</div>

<script>
function test(){ return document.getElementById('1').innerText }
</script>
```

The function test would return "\n foo bar".

The goal is to make an editable text area where links are clickable and where tags are highlighted and where the linking and highlighting is created on the fly while typing.

My approach is:

On every keyup:

- save the cursor position
- cut the text with `innerText`
- parse the links and tags of the text returned by `innerText`
- paste the parsed text into the editable area
- restore the cursor position

Thanks!

Comment: I might be here very late, but surely all you want is the current text node that the user is editing? So all you ever need to replace is the value of the text node that the cursor is in. If text is selected and converted to a link (say), then you have to replace the text node with text nodes and an element contianing the selected text as a text node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toString()` method of the `Selection` object in Firefox, which acts a lot like `innerText`. Since you're already saving the cursor position before extracting `innerText` in your example, the following does not bother to save and restore the selection, but otherwise you should be doing that.

```
function getInnerText(el) {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
        text = sel.toString();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: i like the solution but the lost of the old selection is an undesired side effect. Because restoring the old selection triggers an onfocus event. Reading the innerText property doesn't trigger an onfocus event

Answer (score 1):

Firefox may implement innerText since Aryeh Gregor is writing a specification for innerText.

See http://aryeh.name/spec/innertext/innertext.html and http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-February/030179.html

Comment: As a comment, here we are in May 2012 and HTML5 does not include innerText yet, though it does have [textContent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#textcontent).